# SQLite Studio - Update with Join

Tags: sqlite

I have read that update joins in SQLite are not supported, is there a way to convert a SQL update to SQLite?

```
Update Items
    Set Monitored = '1'

from Items
left join ItemsLoc on ItemsLoc.ItemId = Item.Id

where ItemsLoc.Loc is null
```

I am looking to update a column from Items table where the table/column ItemsLoc.Loc has a null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out.

```
Update Items
Set Monitored ='1'
Where Items.Id in (Select Items.Id from Items Left Join ItemsLoc on ItemsLoc.ItemID = Items.Id where ItemsLoc.Loc is null)
```

Comment: then accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

If `ItemsLoc.Loc` is not nullable then

```sql
UPDATE Items
SET Monitored = '1'
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM ItemsLoc 
                   WHERE ItemsLoc.ItemId = Item.Id )
```